# mysqli_num_rows not returning what is expected

Tags: php, function, mysqli, return

I have a user registration page.  Everything is working on the page, except the check for when a username is already in use by another user.  My PHP ("..." implies there is other code in between that isn't relevant):

```
$login = mysqli_connect("localhost","***","***","***"); // hidden for obvious reasons

function usernameTaken($name)
{
    $query = "SELECT * FROM useraccs WHERE username='$name' LIMIT 1";

    return mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($login,$query)) > 0;
}

...

$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($login,$_POST["username"]);

....

if (usernameTaken($username))
    $error.= "Username is already in use.<br />";
```

This is not working, even if I put in a string literal in the query that I KNOW is in my SQL table.  In my HTML I have this:

```
<?php 
$query = "SELECT * FROM useraccs WHERE username='$username' LIMIT 1";

if (mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($login,$query)) > 0)
    $error.= "Username is already in use.<br />";

echo $error;
?>
```

When I submit the registration form with a username I know is in my SQL table, this code actually works (`mysqli_num_rows` returns 1 as expected) and the error gets echoed).  Even though the code should do the exact same thing in both scenarios, it just isn't working in the function.  The functions always returns false no matter what I put into it.

The only reason I'm using a function is for aesthetics.  I know I could just use the second example and it would work, but I can't for the life of me figure out why the function won't work.  I'm using multiple other functions in the exact same style (but not with `mysqli_num_rows`)  for other parts of this page and they are working fine.

I even tried returning an array from the query in the function, but nothing comes back.  I must be missing something fundamental about PHP functions...

Comment: Is `$login` a global variable?

Comment: Right, sorry, $login is my database connection credentials that are in a separate PHP file.  I have confirmed that is not the issue, as it works elsewhere on the page.

Comment: You need to either define it as a global variable inside the function or have it as a parameter. Try adding `global $login;` on the first line of your function or have login as a parameter that you pass.

Comment: The variable isn't within the scope of the function.

Comment: You know what, now that you say that, I ran into this EXACT problem before.  The problem is I only wrote JavaScript for so long that I still think of scope in that sense.  I really need to learn more about PHP scope.  Thank you so much!

Comment: Added the answer for future reference :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable is out of the scope of the function. You can either do:

## 1 - Use global

```
$login = mysqli_connect("localhost","***","***","***"); // hidden for obvious reasons

function usernameTaken($name)
{
    global $login;
    $query = "SELECT * FROM useraccs WHERE username='$name' LIMIT 1";

    return mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($login,$query)) > 0;
}
```

## 2 - Put it in the functions parameters

```
$login = mysqli_connect("localhost","***","***","***"); // hidden for obvious reasons

function usernameTaken($name, $login)
{
    $query = "SELECT * FROM useraccs WHERE username='$name' LIMIT 1";

    return mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($login,$query)) > 0;
}
```